# Почему «тефтели» только множественного числа?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Как одну штуку тогда назвать, если Т. одна в тарелке лежит?

Comment: Поискал. Словари действительно дружно утверждают, что формы ед.ч. нет. В разговорной речи она, разумеется, есть. Вот здесь, пожалуй, наиболее развернутое [обсуждение](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=44039.0)

Comment: Я в нескольких словарях видел единственное число м. р. (тефтЕль), среди них - Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка Т.Ф. (!) Ивановой, 2005 (второе издание). Исторически - да, когда-то не было, при заимствовании немецкое окончание -i не означало множественного числа в русском (как и в слове "чахохбили"), это было просто блюдо из мелких шариков. https://imwerden.de/pdf/ivanova_orfoepichesky_slovar_russkogo_yazyka_2005.pdf Такое употребление реально имеет место, у меня нет вопросов к факту фиксации слова.